# Convert ES6 JavaScript to ES5 without transpiler

Tags: javascript

I am not familiar with new JavaScript ES6 coding conventions and have been given some code where I need it to be plain old JavaScript ES5.

I need to convert this JS code without the use of Babel or any other transpiler. I cannot use Babel as I am not allowed to use it at work.

I realise that all the "const" can be converted to "var" but unsure of new arrow functions and other items.

I have tried converting but getting:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: line is not defined

The ES6 code that I would like converted to ES5 is:

```
const data = [{ "rec": "1", "region": "LEFT", "intrface": "Line-1" },{ "rec": "1", "region": "LEFT", "intrface": "Line-2" },{ "rec": "1", "region": "RIGHT", "intrface": "Line-3" },{ "rec": "1", "region": "RIGHT", "intrface": "Line-4" }];

const s = Snap("#svg");
const height = 40;
const canvasWidth = 400;
const lineWidth = 180;
const rightOffset = canvasWidth/2 - lineWidth;

const leftLines = data.filter((line) => !isRightLine(line));
const rightLines = data.filter(isRightLine);

leftLines.forEach(drawLine);
rightLines.forEach(drawLine);

const numberOfLines = Math.max(leftLines.length, rightLines.length);
const rectSize = 20;
const rectangles = [];

for (let i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
    rectangles.push(drawRect(i));
}

function drawLine(data, index) {
    const {intrface} = data;
    const isRight = isRightLine(data);
    const x = isRight ? canvasWidth/2 + rightOffset : 0;
  const y = height * (index + 1);
  const stroke = isRight ? 'red' : 'black';

    const line = s.line(x, y, x + 180, y);
  line.attr({
    stroke,
    strokeWidth: 1
  });

  const text = s.text(x + 10, y - 5, intrface);

  text.attr({
    fill: stroke,
    cursor: 'pointer'
  });

  text.click(() => {
    console.log('clicked', data);

    //window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
  });
}

function isRightLine({region}) {
    return region === 'RIGHT';
}

function drawRect(index) {
    const x = canvasWidth/2 - rectSize/2;
  const y = height * (index + 1) - rectSize/2;
    const rectangle = s.rect(x, y, rectSize, rectSize);

  rectangle.attr({
    fill: 'black'
  });

  console.log('rr', x, y);

  return rectangle;
}
```

Comment: Conversion alone might not suffice if let/const were used correct you might ahve to refactor it with hoisting. Also why no use of babel ?

Comment: Why not just use Babel and have a look at the output? They get most of it right.

Comment: Those two instances of arrow functions can trivially replaced with function expressions and nothing will break.

Comment: Is the restriction of using Babel a technical one or ideological one? If it's the latter and you're asking people to convert the code for you, how can you be sure they didn't just run it through Babel?

Comment: Run Babel on the code at home.

Comment: You need to show us the code after you converted it.

Comment: All good now - seems to be working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will assume that since you are not very familiar with es6 you are probably not very familiar with `babeljs.io` which gives you an option to convert back:

Check this [link](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=const%20data%20%3D%20%5B%7B%20%22rec%22%3A%20%221%22%2C%20%22region%22%3A%20%22LEFT%22%2C%20%22intrface%22%3A%20%22Line-1%22%20%7D%2C%7B%20%22rec%22%3A%20%221%22%2C%20%22region%22%3A%20%22LEFT%22%2C%20%22intrface%22%3A%20%22Line-2%22%20%7D%2C%7B%20%22rec%22%3A%20%221%22%2C%20%22region%22%3A%20%22RIGHT%22%2C%20%22intrface%22%3A%20%22Line-3%22%20%7D%2C%7B%20%22rec%22%3A%20%221%22%2C%20%22region%22%3A%20%22RIGHT%22%2C%20%22intrface%22%3A%20%22Line-4%22%20%7D%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20s%20%3D%20Snap(%22%23svg%22)%3B%0D%0Aconst%20height%20%3D%2040%3B%0D%0Aconst%20canvasWidth%20%3D%20400%3B%0D%0Aconst%20lineWidth%20%3D%20180%3B%0D%0Aconst%20rightOffset%20%3D%20canvasWidth%2F2%20-%20lineWidth%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20leftLines%20%3D%20data.filter((line)%20%3D%3E%20!isRightLine(line))%3B%0D%0Aconst%20rightLines%20%3D%20data.filter(isRightLine)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AleftLines.forEach(drawLine)%3B%0D%0ArightLines.forEach(drawLine)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20numberOfLines%20%3D%20Math.max(leftLines.length%2C%20rightLines.length)%3B%0D%0Aconst%20rectSize%20%3D%2020%3B%0D%0Aconst%20rectangles%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afor%20(let%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%20numberOfLines%3B%20i%2B%2B)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20rectangles.push(drawRect(i))%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20drawLine(data%2C%20index)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20%7Bintrface%7D%20%3D%20data%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20isRight%20%3D%20isRightLine(data)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20x%20%3D%20isRight%20%3F%20canvasWidth%2F2%20%2B%20rightOffset%20%3A%200%3B%0D%0A%20%20const%20y%20%3D%20height%20*%20(index%20%2B%201)%3B%0D%0A%20%20const%20stroke%20%3D%20isRight%20%3F%20%27red%27%20%3A%20%27black%27%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20line%20%3D%20s.line(x%2C%20y%2C%20x%20%2B%20180%2C%20y)%3B%0D%0A%20%20line.attr(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20stroke%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20strokeWidth%3A%201%0D%0A%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20const%20text%20%3D%20s.text(x%20%2B%2010%2C%20y%20-%205%2C%20intrface)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20text.attr(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fill%3A%20stroke%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20cursor%3A%20%27pointer%27%0D%0A%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20text.click(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%27clicked%27%2C%20data)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fwindow.location.href%20%3D%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20isRightLine(%7Bregion%7D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20region%20%3D%3D%3D%20%27RIGHT%27%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20drawRect(index)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20x%20%3D%20canvasWidth%2F2%20-%20rectSize%2F2%3B%0D%0A%20%20const%20y%20%3D%20height%20*%20(index%20%2B%201)%20-%20rectSize%2F2%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20rectangle%20%3D%20s.rect(x%2C%20y%2C%20rectSize%2C%20rectSize)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20rectangle.attr(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fill%3A%20%27black%27%0D%0A%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20console.log(%27rr%27%2C%20x%2C%20y)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20return%20rectangle%3B%0D%0A%7D) up.

```
"use strict";

var data = [{ "rec": "1", "region": "LEFT", "intrface": "Line-1" }, { "rec": "1", "region": "LEFT", "intrface": "Line-2" }, { "rec": "1", "region": "RIGHT", "intrface": "Line-3" }, { "rec": "1", "region": "RIGHT", "intrface": "Line-4" }];

var s = Snap("#svg");
var height = 40;
var canvasWidth = 400;
var lineWidth = 180;
var rightOffset = canvasWidth / 2 - lineWidth;

var leftLines = data.filter(function (line) {
  return !isRightLine(line);
});
var rightLines = data.filter(isRightLine);

leftLines.forEach(drawLine);
rightLines.forEach(drawLine);

var numberOfLines = Math.max(leftLines.length, rightLines.length);
var rectSize = 20;
var rectangles = [];

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
  rectangles.push(drawRect(i));
}

function drawLine(data, index) {
  var intrface = data.intrface;

  var isRight = isRightLine(data);
  var x = isRight ? canvasWidth / 2 + rightOffset : 0;
  var y = height * (index + 1);
  var stroke = isRight ? 'red' : 'black';

  var line = s.line(x, y, x + 180, y);
  line.attr({
    stroke: stroke,
    strokeWidth: 1
  });

  var text = s.text(x + 10, y - 5, intrface);

  text.attr({
    fill: stroke,
    cursor: 'pointer'
  });

  text.click(function () {
    console.log('clicked', data);

    //window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
  });
}

// you might want to change this - howeverever you will have to change everywhere in the code that calls isRightLine to pass a primitive vs an object.
function isRightLine(_ref) {
  var region = _ref.region;

  return region === 'RIGHT';
}

function drawRect(index) {
  var x = canvasWidth / 2 - rectSize / 2;
  var y = height * (index + 1) - rectSize / 2;
  var rectangle = s.rect(x, y, rectSize, rectSize);

  rectangle.attr({
    fill: 'black'
  });

  console.log('rr', x, y);

  return rectangle;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Neta Meta. Will try the code and see how I go. Will let you know.

Comment: sounds good. thanks. it should work fine it just transpile the code back is all.

Comment: Thanks for your help. As I mentioned at the beginning, I wasn't aware that I could do the reverse from es6 to es5 using babeljs.io. This is an area I haven't had a chance to investigate as yet. All worked fine with your conversion. Appreciate all the feedback and help.